# Making specific count system with prefixes

Tags: algorithm, numbers, queue

There is a problem,
If we have 2 items with numbers **10 and 11** in list,
there is a need to insert some more items between them,
There is no way to change item numbers (**they are locked**)

So, here is a valid numbers with prefixes between 10 and 11

```
10, 10aaA, 10aA, 10A, 10Aa, 10B, 10aB, 10C, 11
```

is there some algorithm for searching such numbers?

Comment: bonus points for decoding the question!

Comment: So the order is "numbers first", than lowercase characters in alphabetical order, than uppercase - right?

Comment: do you want to make (see title) or search (see last question) such lists?

Comment: hexcoder, actually I need to search such list. For example I need to find out what available numbers between 10aA and 10A

Comment: Martin, almost. For example between 10 and 11, we will have 10A, between 10 and 10A - we will have 10aA, between 10aA and 10A - we will get 10aaA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the classic version numbering scheme?

10, 10.1, 10.2, 10.2.24...11

It's not that hard to implement and it allows you to add practically unlimited entries anywahere.

Comment: biziclop, so how to implement such numbering scheme? maybe there is a ready solution? thanks in advance!

Comment: In which language? But the basic idea is to store your items as a variable length list of numbers and iterate through the lists in parallel when you compare two items.